# build a suggestions list using fuzzywuzzy

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy

I was building a suggestion engine from my database. I'm using fuzzywuzzy module to match user input string with existing database as shown below.

```
if request.method == "GET":
    display_dict = {}
    user_input = request.GET["user_input"]  # get user input
    match_dict = {}

    food_items_obj = food_items.objects.all() # fetch all objects from table

    for items in food_items_obj :
        match = fuzz.ratio(user_input.lower(),items.name.lower()) # try to match the user input with existing names
        match_dict[match] = items.name        # put it one dictionary

    matched_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(match_dict.items(),reverse = True)) # sort the dictionary 
    if max(matched_dict.keys()) == 100: # if exact match then put in a dict and return back
        display_dict[100] = matched_dict[100]
    else :                              
  # if not found then try best matching words.. 
  ###########THIS PART I NEED SOME HELP! #############
        for k,v in matched_dict.items():
            if user_input in v :
                display_dict[k] = v  # if user input is substring of the names in database
            else:
                if k > sum([k for k,v in matched_dict.items()])/len(matched_dict): # best I could think of was to take average of ratio and display items greater than that.  
                display_dict[k] = v

    return render(request,"suggestions/home.html",{'recommendations_list':display_dict,'time_taken': time_taken})
```

So I need some inputs on the else part. I'm not able to pick the right exact words which I want from the database.

```
Example input :
user input : gobi
suggestions that came up:
Did you mean maaza ## unexpected word 
Did you mean gobi 65
Did you mean gobi pepper fry
Did you mean gobi parota
Did you mean kadai gobi
Did you mean aloo gobi
```

How to improve this suggestions ? What more libraries can I use ? What could be the other best (best in the sense of memory and time) possible way to do the same ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you using the ratio `sum([k for k,v in matched_dict.items()])/len(matched_dict)` for? Are you trying to approximate edit distance?